# MongoDB connection error from NodeJS backend using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I have deployed a mongodb replicaset which I am trying to connect to using a node js backend application. 
My connection code is as follows:

```
mongoose.connect(config.database, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  dbName:"db7_0",
  user:'****',
  pass:'****'

}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('The connection to the database could not be established. Error details: ', err);
});
```

'config.database' is the connection URL which I have put together using the mongodb documentation and is the following:

```
  database: "mongodb://user:pw@xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/db7_0?replicaSet=rs0"
```

Note: 'user', 'pw' and 'xxx' are just placeholders for the real details which I have used in the connection string.

When I start up the server and the database connection is created, my logs show the following:
[image]

And my application is throwing the following MongoNetworkError:

```
The connection to the database could not be established. Error details:  MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Dev\sc\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server_selection.js:308:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
Database error MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

I've tried many different approaches to fixing the issue, such as specifying the user, password and database in the connection string as well as the mongoose.connect parameters and this did not make any difference. I was initially on Mongoose v5.9.2 (now v5.8.2) and the behaviour is still the same.

Also, please note that running the following in the command prompt does work:

```
mongo "mongodb://user:pw@xx.xx.xxx.xx:27017/db7_0"
```

So i suspect it might be a mongoose error however I am struggling to figure out the issue.

Comment: Does the replica set currently have a primary?

Comment: @Joe yes it does.

Comment: test `mongo "mongodb://user:pw@xx.xx.xxx.xx:27017/db7_0?replicaSet=rs0"`

Comment: Lots of suggestions in here:  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8180.  Have you tried updating Mongoose?  Also, some are reporting that commenting out useUnifiedTopology resolves the issue.

Comment: @Joe Your suggestion lead me to figure out the solution, thank you! It did not work when I added the replicaSet=rs0 option.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue was caused by the configuration of the replicaSet. 
I had configured each of the members of the replicaSet using the ipv6 address of each member, which was not allowing me to connect to the replica set for some reason. I then reconfigured the replica set and changed each host address to the public DNS ipv4 address of each member and it worked.

Comment: Some clarification on this: When you connect to a replica set, the hosts you provide in the connection string are just a seed list.  The client/shell will make a connection to _one_ of those nodes, then ask that node for a list of replica set members.  It then drops the original connection and reconnects using the discovered host information.  This means that the host addresses used in the replica set config must be resolvable and reachable by all clients.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for that explanation. Helps in understanding what is really going on with the replica set conceptually :)